# Help with linear model fitting (MATLAB)

Tags: regression, self-study, linear-model, matlab, computational-statistics

[image: questions][image: initial separate linear models]

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49lSU.png): [image: single linear model for Q4]

Hello

I have fitted two separate linear models to a set of data (resit_eggs_data.txt), of which one spans 1950 to 1990 and the other 1990 onward.

I need help understanding question 4(a).

4(a):  Fit a single Linear Model to the entire data set that captures the same trends as the two models in question 3(a). Do not consider any
improvements you made in question 3(c). (Tip: you may want to define an additional variable.) Explain how the parameter estimates of this
model relate to the parameters estimates of the two separate models in question 3(a)

I have included screenshots of the questions and of my current separate models.

I need to create a single linear model that illustrates the same trends. I have included the plot of the scatter of the data, with the two separate linear models that i created for question 3(a)

I'm not sure how to approach question 4(a), and I'm looking for some guidance. I'm using MATLAB, and any help interpreting the parameters and details of the output of linear models would also be appreciated (what does SE mean and imply, the estimates mean and imply, pvalue mean and imply etc).

Hope this isn't too long winded.

Thanks